# Comments are not wrapped, continued on other side of page

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, firefox

[How do I delete a folder which is nested quite deep and avoid "File name too long"?](https://superuser.com/questions/256105/how-to-delete-a-folder-which-is-nested-quite-deep)

The comments for the first answer aren't wrapping, and seem to be hiding behind the side bar, and continuing on the other side in Firefox 4.0 on Windows

Comment: (It's a bug in Firefox 4; see updated answer.)

Comment: This is fixed as a side-effect of [this fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91498/is-there-a-css-problem-on-stackoverflow/91512#91512), since we don't use soft hyphens anymore.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug in Firefox 4: [Bug 418975 - Soft hyphen not working in tables](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418975). It has meanwhile been fixed, so a future update of Firefox probably resolves this.

Some background:

To avoid comments to mess up with the layout, [soft hyphens](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ad/index.htm) are automatically inserted into comments after 81 characters without whitespace. For me, [that works well](https://superuser.com/questions/256105/how-to-delete-a-folder-which-is-nested-quite-deep/256130#comment-265284):

[image: Comment with a long code fragment]

I have the same issue in Firefox 4.0.1 on Mac OS X, both for code fragments and for normal text in comments. No problem in other browsers though.

Comment: actually, soft hyphens are inserted after 81 non-space characters as a general rule in comment rendering.

Comment: Indeed, @Jeff, same soft hyphen issue in normal comment text, like [here in the sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/68144#68144). [Looks fine](http://i.imgur.com/hGRvn.png) in Chrome though.

Comment: @Jeff, I found the soft hyphen bug report for Firefox 4. Just for your information, it is related to the tables. (Shouldn't this be on MSO to avoid duplicates?)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are referring to [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/256105/how-to-delete-a-folder-which-is-nested-quite-deep/256130#comment-265284) which could wrap differently for you.

**Confirmed on a portable browser Windows 7 x64 Firefox 4 RTM**:

[image]

**Doesn't occur on my current browser Windows 7 x64 Firefox 6.0a1 (2011-04-14)**.

Comment: yup. that's what i was referring to :)