# Display Bug: Showing More Comments Causes Comments to Get Cut Off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, css

The `<div class="comments">` element surrounds a table element where comments are displayed. `.comments` declares `width:660px;`. The table is styled with `.comments > table{width:100%;}`.

When using the Chrome browser to view the page, and using Chrome's "Web Content > Font size" advanced control set to "Large", clicking the "show *x* more comments" control at the bottom of the "comments" `div` appears to cause the table's width to exceed the div's width. The right-most part of comments long enough to require wrapping to a new line appear to be displayed underneath the right-column content.

[image: show _x_ more comments]

[image: comments load under right column]

This issue persists at different resolutions.

I'm using Google Chrome, Version 24.0.1312.57 m on a Windows 7 Pro SP1 system, with the system text size set to "small (default)".

Possibly related to [Comments are not wrapped, continued on other side of page](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2399/comments-are-not-wrapped-continued-on-other-side-of-page).

Answer (score 1):

We do not support font-size only changes, zoom is the appropriate method to enlarge the page.  We can't reasonably support *portions* of the page getting larger and smaller with a single layout that breaks under no conditions.  Zoom allows people to get a larger font for readability without the trade-offs in layout breakage, so that's the model we support for accessibility.